# Can someone with the Holy Magic Ability and Virtue learn Miraculous effects (Methods and Powers)?

Tags: ars-magica-5, ars-magica

Page 67 and 69 of Ars Magica Realms of Power: The Divine describe that one of the benefits of using Holy Magic is the use of the Holy Power guidelines. Does this mean they can gain the Miraculous effect abilities from pages 45 to 56?

Answer (score 2):

According to *Realms of Power: The Divine* page 47, True Faith functions like the gift in that you can learn divine supernatural abilities with it, but says nothing about the Gift being able to do so. Because of this, you would need True Faith to learn Methods and Powers. The same page also says that Holy Traditions can initiate it's members into the Method and Power virtues with rules described in pages 13-16 of *The Mysteries*.